# Lua self references

Tags: lua, this, self

How exacyly do you get variables within a program with self?

Like in Java you have:

```
private int a

public void sa(int a) { this.a = a}
public void ga() { return this.a }
```

VB has 'ME' and C# has 'this' etc.

But whats the Lua equivalent of this? Is this in the right direction?

```
local a

function sa(a)
    self.a = a
end
```

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question

Comment: Really, wen I tried it didn't seem to work

Comment: yeah, that doesn't work. attempt to index a nil value (global 'self')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat how you are saying it, but the OOP approach is a little bit different. The following is actually the method.

```
local t = {
    a
}
t.__index = t

function t:sa(x)
    self.a = x
end
```

And then, to call the function:

```
t:sa(21)
```

or

```
t.sa( t, "some string this time?" )
```

Comment: Can you explain what __index does here exactly?

Comment: @ThomasFarley `__index` here is merely [implementing inheritance](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html).

Comment: there is no "true" OOP approach in Lua, as it does not define any OOP limitations, the only thing Lua provides in terms of remote OOP is the syntactic sugar of `table:method()`. The construct `local t = { a }` will create an empty table, unless a variable `a` is defined, in which case the value of variable `a` is written at index `1` to the table. And the `__index` key is useless by the way without `setmetatable`.

Answer (score 16):

In lua, you dont have a specific class implementation but you can use a table to simulate it.
To make things simpler, Lua gives you some "syntactic sugar":

To declare a class member you can use this full equivalent syntazes

```
  function table.member(self,p1,p2)
  end
```

or

```
  function table:member(p1,p2)
  end
```

or

```
  table.member = function(self,p1,p2)
  end
```

Now, comes the tricky part:

Invoking

```
table:member(1,2)
```

you get:

> self=table,p1=1,p2=2

invoking

```
table.member(1,2)
```

you get:

> self=1,p1=2,p2=nil

In other words, the `:` mimics a real class, while `.` resemble more to a static use.
The nice thing is you can mix these 2 styles so, for example:

```
table.member(othertable,1,2)
```

gives

> self=othertable,p1=1,p2=2

In this way you can "borrow" method from other classes implementing multiple inheritance

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that `a:b(...)` and `function a:b(...) ... end` is just a syntactic sugar. `self` does not necessarily point to the "current object" because unlike in other programming languages, `self` is just a variable and can be assigned to anything. See the example below for a demonstration:

```lua
function table:member(p1, p2)
 print(self, p1, p2)
end
```

is just

```lua
table.member = function(self, p1, p2)
 print(self, p1, p2)
end
```

and

```lua
table:member(1, 2)
```

is just

```lua
table.member(table, 1, 2)
```

hence

```lua
function table:member(self, p1, p2)
 print(self, p1, p2)
end

table:member(1,2) --self=1 p1=2 p2=nil
```

because that's just

```lua
table.member = function(self, self, p1, p2)
 print(self, p1, p2)
end

table.member(table, 1, 2) --self=1 p1=2 p2=nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly it's exactly what I said.

```
local a

function sa(a)
    self.a = a
end
```

Comment: `local a` is not needed; it doesn't have anything to do with the rest of the code.

Comment: No, it's totally different.  
1) local a is useless, the a used inside function is the one received as parameter and hide the other one  
2) self is a global AND has no value assigned, so it's nil
3) If you ada a line which calls sa, like sa("test") you will receive a run time error:"attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)"